# LINQ nested groups performance

Tags: c#, performance, linq, entity-framework, grouping

i have a full outer join query pulling data from an sql compact database (i use EF6 for mapping):

```
        var query =
            from entry in left.Union(right).AsEnumerable()
            select new
            {
                ...
            } into e
            group e by e.Date.Year into year
            select new
            {
                Year = year.Key,
                Quartals = from x in year
                           group x by (x.Date.Month - 1) / 3 + 1 into quartal
                           select new
                           {
                               Quartal = quartal.Key,
                               Months = from x in quartal
                                        group x by x.Date.Month into month
                                        select new
                                        {
                                            Month = month.Key,
                                            Contracts = from x in month
                                                        group x by x.Contract.extNo into contract
                                                        select new
                                                        {
                                                            ExtNo = month.Key,
                                                            Entries = contract,
                                                        }
                                        }
                           }
            };
```

as you can see i use nested groups to structure results.
the interesting thing is, if i remove AsEnumerable() call, the query takes 3.5x more time to execute: ~210ms vs ~60ms. And when it runs for the first time the difference is much greater: 39000(!)ms vs 1300ms.

My questions are:

1. What am i doing wrong, maybe those groupings should be done in a different way?
2. Why the first execution takes so much time? I know expression trees should be built etc, but 39 seconds?
3. Why linq to db is slower than linq to entities in my case? Is it generally slower and its better to load data from db if possible before processing?

thakns!

Comment: The `AsEnumerable` brings the data into memory before grouping. Removing it means that multiple subqueries are run against the db, causing it to be slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your three questions:

> Maybe those groupings should be done in a different way?

No. If you want nested groupings you can only do that by groupings within groupings.

You *can* group by multiple fields at once:

```
from entry in left.Union(right)
select new
{
    ...
} into e
group e by new 
           { 
               e.Date.Year, 
               Quartal = (e.Date.Month - 1) / 3 + 1, 
               e.Date.Month, 
               contract = e.Contract.extNo 
           } into grp
select new
{
    Year = grp.Key,
    Quartal = grp.Key,
    Month = grp.Key,
    Contracts = from x in grp
                select new
                {
                    ExtNo = month.Key,
                    Entries = contract,
                }
}
```

This will remove a lot of complexity from the generated query so it's likely to be (much) faster *without* `AsEnumerable()`. But the result is quite different: a flat group (Year, Quartal, etc, in one row), not a nested grouping.

> 2. Why the first execution takes so much time?

Because the generated SQL query is probably pretty complex and the database engine's query optimizer can't find a fast execution path.

> 3a. Why is linq to db slower than linq to entities in my case?

Because, apparently, in this case it's much more efficient to fetch the data into memory first and do the groupings by LINQ-to-objects. This effect will be more significant if `left` and `right` represent more or less complex queries themselves. In that case, the generated SQL can get hugely bloated, because it has to process two sources of complexity in one statement, which may lead to many repeated identical sub queries. By outsourcing the grouping, the database is probably left with a relative simple query and of course the grouping in memory is never affected by the complexity of the SQL query.

> 3b. Is it generally slower and its better to load data from db if possible before processing?

No, not generally. I'd even say, hardly ever. In this case it is because (as I can see) you don't filter data. If however the part before `AsEnumerable()` would return millions of records and you would apply filtering afterwards, the query without `AsEnumerable()` would probably be much faster, because the filtering is done in the database.

Therefore, you should always keep an eye on generated SQL. It's unrealistic to expect that EF will always generate a super optimized SQL statement. It hardly ever will. Its primary focus is on correctness (and it does an exceptional job there), performance is secondary. It's the developer's job to make LINQ-to-Entities and LINQ-to-object work together as a slick team.

Comment: By the way, next time, it would be better to ask one question at a time. StackOverflow likes to have questions that can be answered in a way that one answer is likely to bubble up as *the* answer. That's hard if three people would answer your three questions.

Answer (score 1):

Using `AsEnumerable()` will convert a type that implements `IEnumerable<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>` itself.

Read this topic https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435.aspx

`AsEnumerable<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>)` can be used to choose between query implementations when a sequence implements `IEnumerable<T>` but also has a different set of public query methods available. For example, given a generic class `Table` that implements `IEnumerable<T>` and has its own methods such as `Where`, `Select`, and `SelectMany`, a call to `Where` would invoke the public `Where` method of `Table`. A `Table` type that represents a database table could have a `Where` method that takes the predicate argument as an expression tree and converts the tree to SQL for remote execution. If remote execution is not desired, for example because the predicate invokes a local method, the `AsEnumerable<TSource>` method can be used to hide the custom methods and instead make the standard query operators available.

When you invoke `AsEnumerable()` first, it won't convert LINQ-to-SQL but will instead load the table in memory as the `Where` is enumerating it.  Since now it is loaded in memory, it's execution is faster.